# Laravel Datatables get data from GET variables

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

**Laravel 5.5**

I have a search view where users can type in the `text input` fields to search a table. The request goes to GET variables onto the results blade.

Inside the results blade, there is a Laravel ajax table. https://datatables.yajrabox.com/

I can't figure out how to get pass the GET variables in the URL to the search Laravel ajax request.

Ultimately, I want to be able to pass `$_GET` lead_name, lead_phone, etc to this ajax request. How can I accomplish that?

Here is my datatables script at the bottom of the page:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.datatable').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: '{{ route('SearchResults') }}',
            method: 'GET'
        },
        columns: [
            { data: 'lead_name', name: 'leads.lead_name' },
            { data: 'lead_merchant_id', name: 'leads.lead_merchant_id'},
            { data: 'lead_address_city', name: 'leads.lead_address_city' },
            { data: 'lead_address_state', name: 'leads.lead_address_state' },
            { data: 'accountstatus_description', name: 'accountstatus.accountstatus_description' },
            { data: 'firstlast_name', name: 'name' }
        ],
        rowReorder: {
            selector: 'td:nth-child(0)' 
           },
        responsive: true
    });
});
```

If I run a dd on my searchresults route:

```
public function SearchResults(request $request) {
    dd($request);
}
```

it doesn't return any of the previous GET data.

Comment: What is the response?  Are you getting past the csrf middleware?

Comment: @TarekAdam It's showing some weird data such as the column names, order, start, length, etc which are not any of my get variables. The library https://datatables.yajrabox.com/ that I'm using takes care of any csrf middleware.

Comment: Is all that stuff in the post response or get response?

Comment: @TarekAdam It's in both. The data I'm needing to pass to the ajax is from the GET params in the url.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to send by GET method , You can easily use the POST method in the following way :

You should have a form on your page with the POST method and unique ID

```
<form method="POST" id="search-form" role="form">
      {{csrf_field()}}
      <input type="text" name="lead_phone">
</form>
```

On your page, write this jquery code that runs this code when you submit the form

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search-form').on('submit', function(e) {
        table.draw();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Then use the following code for your DataTable section

```
$(function() {
  var table = $('.datatable').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        url: '{{ route('SearchResults') }}',
        type: "post",
        data: function (d) {
              d.lead_phone = $('input[name=visited]').val();
              d._token = _token;
        },
    },
    columns: [
        { data: 'lead_name', name: 'leads.lead_name' },
        { data: 'lead_merchant_id', name: 'leads.lead_merchant_id'},
        { data: 'lead_address_city', name: 'leads.lead_address_city' },
        { data: 'lead_address_state', name: 'leads.lead_address_state' },
        { data: 'accountstatus_description', name: 'accountstatus.accountstatus_description' },
        { data: 'firstlast_name', name: 'name' }
    ],
    rowReorder: {
        selector: 'td:nth-child(0)' 
       },
    responsive: true
  });
});
```

If the data is sent by Query String, there's no need for a jquery code and form, just write down the following code in your DataTable section

```
$(function() {
  var table = $('.datatable').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        url: '{{ route('SearchResults') }}',
        type: "post",
        data: function (d) {
              d.lead_phone = '{{$_GET['lead_phone']}}';
              d._token = '{{csrf_token()}}';
        },
    },
    columns: [
        { data: 'lead_name', name: 'leads.lead_name' },
        { data: 'lead_merchant_id', name: 'leads.lead_merchant_id'},
        { data: 'lead_address_city', name: 'leads.lead_address_city' },
        { data: 'lead_address_state', name: 'leads.lead_address_state' },
        { data: 'accountstatus_description', name: 'accountstatus.accountstatus_description' },
        { data: 'firstlast_name', name: 'name' }
    ],
    rowReorder: {
        selector: 'td:nth-child(0)' 
       },
    responsive: true
  });
});
```

And then get the data you send to controller

```
public function DataTable(Request $request)
{
   $lead_phone = $request->get('lead_phone');
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Comment: I am getting error like below in this. 
Uncaught ReferenceError: table is not defined.
I am using type post in ajax request and I have to receive data in the same page from where the form is posted.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the `method` of sending data.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.datatable').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        method: post,
        ajax: '{{ route('SearchResults') }}',
        columns: [
            { data: 'lead_name', name: 'leads.lead_name' },
            { data: 'lead_merchant_id', name: 'leads.lead_merchant_id'},
            { data: 'lead_address_city', name: 'leads.lead_address_city' },
            { data: 'lead_address_state', name: 'leads.lead_address_state' },
            { data: 'accountstatus_description', name: 'accountstatus.accountstatus_description' },
            { data: 'firstlast_name', name: 'name' }
        ],
        rowReorder: {
            selector: 'td:nth-child(0)' 
           },
        responsive: true
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried this.. the default method is POST. You don't have to declare it unless needed.  I'm needing a GET request. If I change it to get and run a `dd(request $request) on the ajax request it doesn't return the data.